# Errors nltk.gaac.demo() is run

Tags: nltk

When I run nltk.gaac.demo()

can you please help me if i am missing out on something ? I get the following errors.

I am using nltk 3.0.1

```
Python 3.4.1 (v3.4.1:c0e311e010fc, May 18 2014, 10:38:22) [MSC v.1600 32 bit   (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.gaac.demo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\cluster\gaac.py", line 150, in demo
clusters = clusterer.cluster(vectors, True)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\cluster\gaac.py", line 41, in cluster
return VectorSpaceClusterer.cluster(self, vectors, assign_clusters, trace)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\cluster\util.py", line 57, in cluster
self.cluster_vectorspace(vectors, trace)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\cluster\gaac.py", line 79, in          cluster_vectorspace
self.update_clusters(self._num_clusters)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\cluster\gaac.py", line 99, in     update_clusters
clusters = self._dendrogram.groups(num_clusters)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\cluster\util.py", line 213, in groups
return root.groups(n)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\cluster\util.py", line 161, in groups
queue.sort()
TypeError: unorderable types: _DendrogramNode() < _DendrogramNode()
```

Comment: Looks like you've found a bug in the demo to me - It's telling you that the `_DendrogramNode()` object (see [source here](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/cluster/util.py#L129)) is not orderable, therefore trying to sort a queue of them is not possible.

Comment: thats unfortunate . i am trying learn nltk

Comment: OK - it doesn't do this on my install.  Which is a bit weird. I note you're using Python 3.4.1 - do you happen to have an older version around? I use 2.7. It might be their Python 3.x support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be an `nltk` module compatibility issue between Python 2.x and 3.x .  I explain below, you can hack a solution which is in the last section

### Explanation

On my machine, in Python 2.7, `nltk.gaac.demo()` yields:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:18) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.gaac.demo()
None [array([ 0.70710678,  0.70710678]), array([ 0.4472136 ,  0.89442719]), arra
y([ 0.89442719,  0.4472136 ]), array([ 1.,  0.]), array([ 0.5547002 ,  0.8320502
9]), array([ 0.9486833 ,  0.31622777])]
Clusterer: <GroupAverageAgglomerative Clusterer n=4>
Clustered: [array([3, 3]), array([1, 2]), array([4, 2]), array([4, 0]), array([2
, 3]), array([3, 1])]
As: [0, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]

     +---------+---------+---------+
     |         |         |         |
     |         |         +-----------------------------+
     |         |         |         |                   |
     |         +-----------------------------+         |
     |         |         |         |         |         |
[ 3.  3.] [ 1.  2.] [ 4.  2.] [ 4.  0.] [ 2.  3.] [ 3.  1.]
classify([3 3]): 0
```

whereas in Python 3.3 I see the exact behaviour OP reports for Python 3.4.1.

I have raised a bug report with the [`nltk` developers here](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues).

[This blog](http://python3porting.com/problems.html) on migrating Python 2 to Python 3 notes that:

> Unorderable types, **cmp** and cmp
>     Under Python 2 the most common way of making types sortable is to
>   implement a **cmp**() method that in turn uses the builtin cmp()
>   function
>
> ...
>
> Since having both **cmp**() and rich comparison methods violates the
>   principle of there being only one obvious way of doing something,
>   Python 3 ignores the **cmp**() method. In addition to this, the cmp()
>   function is gone! This typically results in your converted code
>   raising a TypeError: unorderable types error. So you need to replace
>   the **cmp**() method with rich comparison methods instead. To support
>   sorting you only need to implement **lt**(), the method used for the
>   “less then” operator, <.

### Solution

To get yourself going - add a `__lt__()` function to the _DendrogramNode class:

- Open `C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\nltk\cluster\util.py` in an editor of your choice
- Find the line `class _DendrogramNode(object)` (line 129 in my installation)
- add a less than function - so your code looks like:

  ```
  class _DendrogramNode(object):
     """ Tree node of a dendrogram. """

      def __lt__(self, comparator):
          return self._value.any() < comparator._value.any()
  ```
- final step (to account for the new division rules in Python 3)
- find the line `return '%s%s%s' % (lhalf*left, centre, right*rhalf)` (line 247 on mine with the addition above)
- replace with `return '%s%s%s' % (int(lhalf)*left, centre, right*int(rhalf))`

You then get the output you want:

```
Python 3.3.0 (v3.3.0:bd8afb90ebf2, Sep 29 2012, 10:57:17) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AM
D64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import nltk
>>> nltk.gaac.demo()
None [array([ 0.70710678,  0.70710678]), array([ 0.4472136 ,  0.89442719]), arra
y([ 0.89442719,  0.4472136 ]), array([ 1.,  0.]), array([ 0.5547002 ,  0.8320502
9]), array([ 0.9486833 ,  0.31622777])]
Clusterer: <GroupAverageAgglomerative Clusterer n=4>
Clustered: [array([3, 3]), array([1, 2]), array([4, 2]), array([4, 0]), array([2
, 3]), array([3, 1])]
As: [0, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]

     +---------+---------+---------+
     |         |         |         |
     |         |         +-----------------------------+
     |         |         |         |                   |
     |         +-----------------------------+         |
     |         |         |         |         |         |
[ 3.  3.] [ 1.  2.] [ 4.  2.] [ 4.  0.] [ 2.  3.] [ 3.  1.]
classify([3 3]): 0
```

---

My version of the hacked util.py file is available as a [github gist](http://gist.github.com/rsnape/0d9c7a1ac62dd90dffa0).

Comment: I get the errors below. May I request you to share your util.py ? also, can you kindly verify your version of nltk ? 
>>> import nltk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\__init__.py", line 147, in <module>
    from nltk import cluster; from .cluster import *
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\cluster\__init__.py", line 82, in <module>
    from nltk.cluster.util import (VectorSpaceClusterer, Dendrogram,
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\nltk\cluster\util.py", line 131
    def __lt__(self, comparator):

Comment: Sure - it's here: https://gist.github.com/rsnape/0d9c7a1ac62dd90dffa0.  I just realised I had to hack an extra bit onto the `value` (adding `.any()` to make it work - sorry I missed in my answer (I was rushing) - I will amend.

Comment: Thanks @JRichardSnape, great answer! If it's alright, I'll write a PR to merge your fixes and you will be attributed as an NLTK contributor  =)

Comment: @alvas Sure - no problem :) In fact, thanks!  I'm username `rsnape` on github, if that's relevant.

Comment: Let me also check how should 1D array be "compared" and do the PR together with a distance metric other than solely using .any()

Comment: @alvas For info - I just remembered I started a discussion on this here: https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/873 but I can see I never got as far as resolving a distance metric and making a PR.  Thanks for taking up the baton!

Comment: Thanks @JRichardSnape, the PR is merged =) https://github.com/nltk/nltk/pull/1456